# Access level issue with File Model in getStream

Tags: swift, getstream-io

I m supporting the video file in getStream , but not able to set the mimeType for video file because of internal access level of mimeType property. For Image they have provided the extension but for other type no extension available.

Below is the code for File model in GetStream pod

```
public struct File {
  let name: String
  let data: Data
  var mimeType: MimeType?

  public init(name: String, data: Data) {
    self.name = name.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "."))
    self.data = data
  }
}

public extension File {

init?(name: String, jpegImage: Image, compressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.9) {
    guard let data = jpegImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(name: name, data: data)
    mimeType = Swime.mimeType(byFileExtension: "jpg")
}


init?(name: String, pngImage: Image) {
    guard let data = pngImage.pngData() else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(name: name, data: data)
    mimeType = Swime.mimeType(byFileExtension: "png")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

we don't support uploading video at this time. We recommend using a third party video host and then embedding the URL to the video into the activity.